# VSCode Source Control showing some random files that have not been changed

Tags: visual-studio-code

My VSCode is showing much more files in "Changes" then the actual files that are changed.
Most of them are some static files, scripts... And when I click to see what actually changed, there's no difference. How can I turn off showing such files?

Comment: Do you have any other extensions installed which interact with git?

Comment: @im_baby no, I don't

Answer (score 1):

You can add a '.gitignore' file which have contents like :

```
######################
# Package Files
######################
*.jar
*.war
*.ear
*.db
```

Comment: I have .gitignore file, but it shows files that are not changed